# Apache Maven - deploying to Karaf and running SOAP UI tests

Tags: java, maven, soapui, apache-karaf

I have a question regarding test automation with Apache Maven.

Is it possible to configure Apache Maven to run Unit Tests, then package the Java Project as an OSGI Bundle, deploy it to a Karaf OSGI Container and finally run SOAP UI Tests on it (Cleaning the bundle from the Container is not that important but if someone knows how to do this aswell, I'd be happy to hear about this ;) ).

I know that unit testing, packaging and SOAP UI testing itself is not the problem. But how do I get Maven to execute the steps in the order as described (and especially how can I tell Maven to deploy a bundle to an OSGI Container)?

Greetings,
Pascal

Answer (score 0):

This sound more like an integration test.

If you instrument the OSGI deployment and the running of SoapUI tests via java code, then from the maven perspective it is very simple.

Is this a workable solution for you?

Just set up integration tests via a maven profile and run tests as normal: `mvn clean test -Pintegrationtests`

Comment: Oh yes this would indeed be a workable solution. I did not know that SOAP UI can be integrated in a JUnit test this easy. The only thing I can hardly imagine is how to start up the karaf, package the project as a bundle and deploy it to the running karaf with Java.

Comment: In JBoss Fuse we use a class called `FuseTestSupport`. Since Fuse is based on Karaf, there must be something similar in the karaf core...